# AFHTTPClient sets Authorization Header Field like " Token token='\75845hjhrtje845395748' " But i just want to be the token inside

Tags: ios, http, network-programming, afnetworking

I am currently trying to implement authorization with AFNetworking.
I tried to put the access_token inside the HTTP-Authorizationheader.
But what arrives at the server is like :

```
Token token  = "\fdasfjhalsfh4546"
```

It should be just the token-value inside the Header.
My Code looks like this :

```
- (void)setAuthTokenHeader {
    CredentialStore *store = [[CredentialStore alloc] init];
    [self setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:[store authToken]];
}
```

`[store authToken]` just returns the authtoken itself, so I don't understand why the HTTP-Field-Content looks like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem is way easier then i thought. It seems that Afnetworking appends the token by default to that string :

```
- (void)setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:(NSString *)token {
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token token=\"%@\"", token]];
}
```